# What is an effective way to set up a WiFi network to another floor in one building?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

I dont know a lot about networking and i dont know if my idea is suitable for this situation.

The company i am working has 2 floors in one building.

Floor 2 and Floor 6.

All the computers are on the same network (LAN).
We have one router in 2nd floor and in both of 2 floors we have switches.
In 2nd floor we have UniFi and all the floor has WiFi access.

I was thinking in order to have WiFi access to the 6th floor we need to buy another one UniFi and connect it to the switch of 6th Floor.

Is that correct or do i miss something? Does it need more configuration except of just plug in to the switch?

Comment: So the floors already have a network connection between them. The most important question after that is the logical network structure: Is the WiFi on a separate VLAN? Do both floors share a single broadcast domain?

Answer (score 0):

I *assume* that all your switches have an uplink to one another (If you're using a HP Switch you can telnet and run `sh lldp i r` to obtain the information), so it may be possible to simply configure Wireless Access Points with the same SSID, therefore having range over your floors.

If you're not into configuring or setting that up, something like a [Ubiquiti](https://www.ubnt.com/) (only linking because I have used this product and know how to set them up) to plug into the switch, and the "receiver" at another location. This will broadcast a Wireless network of your choice (you need to configure) and can be used across a fairly large distance.

**Note** that your question is pretty broad though, so there are many options you can take.

Comment: Just a thought too, you could use Wireless Receivers to an extent, but would not suggest.

If you have a PoE switch, something like a Ubiquiti will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your UniFi IP address configuration.

The 2nd floor UniFi already supplying internet connection default IP is 192.168.1.20.

You can connect to UniFi ap 192.168.1.20 using username/password: ubnt/ubnt

Connected by LAN you need to configure the 6th floor UniFi gateway to 192.168.1.20 and change its default IP to 192.168.1.21.